# Ask Question description box filled with default message

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Is this something new?

When I go to "Ask Question" my editor has a default message "Have you seen http://superuser.com..." loaded into. Here is a screenshot of it:

> [image]

I have never seen my editor desc. box with a default message until today. I have posted 30+ questions so far. Also, this is **not** even a "**placeholder text**" (gray text - like in our Profile's About me page). Here, I have to select all and delete it before I can start writing my description.

Can anyone please explain.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a draft from a question you began typing some time ago?

Comment: SE saves drafts of questions. Had you typed this in some time ago?

Comment: @NormalHuman when did change took place?

Comment: @ChrisF I have never seen this before. When did UI change took place?

Comment: @HackerKarma - SE has saved drafts of posts for quite a while now. Several years.

Comment: @ChrisF I have seen the draft saved message BUT I was always given blank desc. window to write the description

Comment: Voted to close as norepro, as this is just some copy/paste shenanigans :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a [*draft* of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/allow-questions-to-be-saved-as-drafts-prior-to-posting).

> If you start asking a question, but do not successfully submit, you will see your last saved question draft the next time you visit the ask a question page.

Either you, or someone else using a computer at which you were logged in, put that in at some point and did not post. Most likely, the text was copy-pasted from the formatting help: click ? in the editor, then "Links", and you will see the text above.

I guess that someone copied that text to use as a template for their own post, and then was interrupted or realized they were logged into someone else's account [yours] on a shared computer.

You should see the word "discard" next to the "Post" button:

[image: discard]

If you click it, the draft will disappear.

Comment: I see a discard button but if you look at the message ... I never typed it... It looks like a default message from the system... +1 for the "discard" finding but now the rest mystery remains to solve.

Comment: I added a likely explanation of the mystery.

Comment: You got that mystery solved... It's loaded from the ? "Links" section and I don;t know how but it is truth. I am accepting your answer. Thanks a million.

Comment: Should I delete the question or leave it for a reference purpose. I feel kinda dumb here... Who knows someone may get in trouble like me... what do you think.

Answer (score 2):

You could have got the text from the `?` on the question textarea box and then clicking "Links", or perhaps you got it from another question/answer as it is official help text so it's quoted on other threads.
[Like this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158721/question-help-text-out-of-date)

It being saved is simply the site's auto draft system, but how it got into your question seems to be the interesting mystery.

Perhaps you saw it on another question or answer, and intended to ask a question about that text, copy/pasted and then forgot/was distracted/browser crashed and forgot..etc?
For example, maybe ask what on Earth "panda" is all about..

If you're on Linux, certain distros have a copy ability just by highlighting text, which can then be pasted in a number of ways (I use middle mouse button). It's possible to accidentally copy/paste text in this way.

Either way though, it was a bit of excitement for you :D but problem solved.

Comment: James, it's probably the Apple's MAGIC Mouse who tricked me...

Comment: I asked this to NormalHuman: Should I delete the question or leave it for a reference purpose. I feel kinda dumb here... Who knows someone may get in trouble like me... what do you think.

Comment: Apple has that too? Nice, I couldn't live without it now :) You cannot delete the question as answers have upvotes. But perhaps someone else will find use of it. I'm sure Stack has enough DB space :D (if it makes you feel better, we can close it as no repro, but don't sweat it, it was a valid question)

Comment: Thanks. Whatever is appropriate is fine with me.